# Should I reply to email from institute director congratulating me for being shortlisted for a position?

Tags: etiquette, independent-researcher, administration

I have received an email from the "director" of a prestigious research institute, sent to me and another candidate, announcing and congratulating that we have been shortlisted for a particular position. He then mentioned that his assistant will contact us to inform us about the interview procedure and the next steps.

I wonder if I have to reply to the email, given it is sent by the director with his e-mail and not his assistance, or administration email, or I have to consider it as a kind of public announcement and just wait for his office to contact me?

Comment: Why is "director" in quotes?

Comment: Because I wanted to emphasize that, basically I was doubtful only because the director has sent the email. Usually, the human resource dept/ administration sends these emails, in such cases, it is easy to decide how to act; I always reply to them. But since in this time the directors himself has sent the email, and states that wait for further contact by the administration, I was not sure replying to him is professional.

Answer (score 4):

A short *thank you* email would be appropriate. "Thank you for the continued interest. I look forward to the interview and the future".

Something along those lines, but you can probably come up with a better statement. It lets them know that you got the message, and, more important, that you are still very interested.

Comment: I might write "good news" instead of "continued interest", to convey more enthusiasm (assuming I have more enthusiasm).